# Git: fatal: Unable to write new index file error on network share

Tags: git

I work on a home automation project on my server via a network share. The reason for this is all the hardware is connected to this server. After coding for a while I can not commit anymore and get the error: `Git: fatal: Unable to write new index file`

When I disconnect my network share and reconnect I can continue for while and after some time it starts over again.

I've checked

- [Git 'fatal: Unable to write new index file'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064513/git-fatal-unable-to-write-new-index-file)
- [git problem : fatal: Unable to write new index file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813962/git-problem-fatal-unable-to-write-new-index-file)

but disk space is not the issue.

I code on a Mac and the server is a RPI running Raspbian. The connection is made via Finder using AFP share. On the Raspbian I run netatalk.

Possible solutions I've thought about:

1. Work on the server, but then I can not use my favourite IDE
2. Work locally on my Mac, but then I can not reach the usb connected hardware on my server.
3. Work locally, push the changes to git and pull on the server, very time consuming since you need to commit every change you make till you can test it on the server.

Comment: why not dev it locally then push to the raspberry pi?

Comment: Because then I cannot reach the usb connected hardware.

Comment: Git is, paradoxically, poor at sharing. Each Git repository "wants" to be in sole command of *every* file under control of Git (basically everything that's not part of the work-tree).